# Define multiple buttons for Windows commands

Tags: python, performance, beginner, console, gui

I'm teaching myself Python.

I wrote this code for work to help me troubleshoot end users PCs. It opens a GUI with a selection of buttons. It's written in python using pyinstaller to convert it to an executable. It's super slow - taking 10-15+ seconds to run on a PC. Why is it so slow and how can I improve it overall?

The command I user for pyinstaller is `pyinstaller -F -w <scriptname.py>`

As an aside, the program opens an elevated command prompt by default. How do I make that an option?

```
from tkinter import *
import os, ctypes, sys

root=Tk()
root.title('Common Fixes')
root.geometry("250x500")

def mapSharedDrives():
        os.system('cmd /c " map_drives.bat')

def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

if is_admin():
    button=[]
    os.system('cmd /c "color a"')
    def showSystemInfo():
        os.system('cmd /c "systeminfo | find /i "Host Name" & systeminfo | find /i "boot time" & pause"')

    def restartPC ():
        os.system('cmd /c "shutdown /r"')
    
    def deleteWindowsCredentials():
        os.system('cmd /c "del %TEMP%\List.txt /s /f /q & del %TEMP%\tokensonly.txt /s /f /q"')
    
    def updateGroupPolicy():
        os.system('cmd /c "del %windir%\system32\GroupPolicy\ /s /f /q & gpupdate /force"')

    def sfcScanNow():
        os.system('cmd /c "sfc /scannow & pause"')

    def restartPrintSpooler():
        os.system('cmd /c "net stop spooler & net start spooler"')
    
    def DISM():
        os.system('cmd /c "DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth & pause"')

    def addSwitchUser():
        os.system('cmd /c "reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v HideFastUserSwitching /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f"')

    def increaseOutlookMessageSize():
        os.system('cmd /c "reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\PST /v MaxLargeFileSize /t REG_DWORD /d 204800 /f & reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\PST /v WarnLargeFileSize /t REG_DWORD /d 184320 /f"')

    def increaseOutlookAttachmentSize():
        os.system('cmd /c "reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook /v MaximumAttachmentSize /t REG_DWORD /d 81920 /f"')
    
    def deleteOutlookFiles():
        os.system('cmd /c "del %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook /s /f /q & del %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook /s /f /q & rmdir %USERPROFILE%\appdata\local\Microsoft\Outlook /s /q & reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles /f & reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\​Software\​Policies\​Microsoft\​office\​14.0\​outlook /f & reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\​Software\​Microsoft\​Office\​15.0\​Outlook /f & reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\​Software\​Microsoft\​Office\​12.0\​Outlook /f & reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\​Software\​Microsoft\​Office\​11.0\​Outlook /f & reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\​Software\​Microsoft\​Office\​10.0\​Outlook /f & pause"')

    buttons = {
        "PC Info &\nLast Restarted": showSystemInfo,
        "Restart the PC": restartPC,
        "Delete Windows\nCredentials": deleteWindowsCredentials,
        "Update Group Policy": updateGroupPolicy,
        "SFC /Scannow": sfcScanNow,
        "Restart Print Spooler": restartPrintSpooler,
        "DISM": DISM,
        "Add Switch User": addSwitchUser,
        "Increase Outlook\nMessage Size": increaseOutlookMessageSize,
        "Increase Outlook\nAttachment Size": increaseOutlookAttachmentSize,
        "Delete Outlook Files": deleteOutlookFiles,

}

    for title, func in buttons.items():
        b = Button(height=2, width=15, text=title, command=func)
        b.pack()

else:
    # Re-run the program with admin rights
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)


buttons = {
        "Map a Network Drive": mapSharedDrives,
        "Admin Scripts":is_admin

}

for title, func in buttons.items():
    b = Button(height=2, width=15, text=title, command=func)
    b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to code review! Asking how to improve the code is fine, however asking "_...How do I make that an option?_" is a feature request, which is not [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapSharedDrives` should be `map_shared_drives` by PEP8.

Never bare `except:`. For `is_admin`, if you know that a specific exception indicates the user is not an admin, catch only that exception.

Move your global code starting with `if is_admin():` into functions.

Don't `os.system('cmd /c x')`; instead call into one of the `subprocess` methods passing `x`, ideally with `shell=False`. Some of your commands shouldn't be external calls at all, such as `del` which should use `pathlib.Path.unlink()`, or `winreg` module instead of the `reg` calls.

An example of invoking `subprocess`:

```
from os import environ
from pathlib import Path
from subprocess import check_output

systeminfo = Path(environ['WINDIR']) / 'system32/systeminfo.exe'
output = check_output((systeminfo,), encoding='utf-8', shell=False)
lines = output.splitlines()
hostname, = (line for line in lines if line.startswith('Host Name'))
boot_time, = (line for line in lines if line.startswith('System Boot Time'))

print(hostname)
print(boot_time)
```

Even this is a poor example, because `hostname` has a Python built-in.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm not sure what mean when you say, "Don't os.system('cmd /c x'); instead call into one of the subprocess methods passing x, ideally with shell=False" , can give me an example? What subprocess method do you recommend?

Comment: Example added; not all subprocess calls will look alike